# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/persistence/Persistence... axis2 and eclipselink

Tags: netbeans, eclipselink, apache-axis

I want to deploy axis2 web services in netbeans, i installed the plugin axis2 in netbeans. Also i use EclipseLink 2.0 to connect a db. My connection is successful when i use in a main class that i created. But when i try to test my web services in netbeans with right click on the services throw this exception:

[ERROR] javax/persistence/Persistence
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/persistence/Persistence
        at db.util.ManageConnection.getStatsEntityManagerFactory(ManageConnection.java:33)
        at services.LoginService.loginService(LoginService.java:31)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCUtil.invokeServiceClass(RPCUtil.java:194)
        at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCInOnlyMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(RPCInOnlyMessageReceiver.java:63)
        at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractMessageReceiver.receive(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:114)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:173)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.util.RESTUtil.invokeAxisEngine(RESTUtil.java:135)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.util.RESTUtil.processURLRequest(RESTUtil.java:130)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet$RestRequestProcessor.processURLRequest(AxisServlet.java:825)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.doGet(AxisServlet.java:271)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:390)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:849)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:454)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class Not found : javax.persistence.Persistence
        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentClassLoader.findClass(DeploymentClassLoader.java:92)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentClassLoader.loadClass(DeploymentClassLoader.java:273)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
        ... 31 more
[ERROR] org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: javax/persistence/Persistence

I can deploy others services that not contain connections with eclipselink (entityManager...)..

I found in others forum with the same problem but they're using hibernate, that the solution is add to classpath this: hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.0.Final.jar, in this link http://www.coderanch.com/t/513512/ORM/databases/Error-java-lang-NoClassDefFoundError-javax

But I dont Know what is the problem with EclipseLink i dont know if i add other library and where.. thank you very much...

This my service class

public class LoginService {

```
EntityManagerFactory emf = ManageConnection.
    getStatsEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceConfiguration.
    getPERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME());

public String prubaServicioWeb(String nombre) {
    return nombre + " Welcome";

}

public void loginService(String whatever) {

    BankJpaController bankController = new
    BankJpaController(emf);
    Bank bank = new Bank();
    bank.setId(null);
    bank.setBankCode("BNSJ");
    bank.setName("Bank of America");
    bankController.create(bank);

}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the javax.persistence classes that come in either the javax.persistence_1.0.0.jar (if using only JPA 1.0) or javax.persistence_2.0.4.v201112161009.jar if using JPA 2.0 (the jar might be named slightly different, this was what was shipped with a 2.4 milestone).

These will be in the jlib/jpa directory of your EclipseLink download.

Comment: Thank you... I put the jar in the library and throw other exception... The return of the entity manager is null, but when i test with a main class the entity manager is successful and i can connect with DB... But i test the web service throw the following exception:  [ERROR] Exception occurred while trying to invoke service method loginService
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at db.controller.BankJpaController.getEntityManager(BankJpaController.java:33)........ I have to consider any other thing?

Comment: When try to enter a class where i import the EntityManager netbeans put this below: Cannot open EntityManager (missing source? but i really put the library an the code compile good :(